# Store smaller pdf file in the server

Tags: php, algorithm, pdf, javascript

Right now I'm working on mobile application which need some pdf files download process from the server. I just wonder how to make those pdf files size smaller. Is there any algorithm or plug-in or library on PHP or javascript that able to make uploaded pdf files are stored in smaller size in the server. So when those files is downloaded by my mobile apps it's doesn't spend so much bandwidth or time.

thx for all the answers and responses.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about PDF files is that they are already pretty much compressed when they are composed, so you're unlikely to see any real performance benefits from compressing them further. You could Zip or Rar them, but as I said, don't expect a resounding benefit.

Comment: the pdf files contain a lot of images, therefore I thought that if i could compress those pdf files again, I get smaller size. cause the size of one pdf files up to 200MB, I think it'll be too much for mobile. Thx btw, for the suggestions